# Знаки препинания при прямой речи со словом «говорит»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова, прямая-речь

В тексте вставлены слова некоего лица, пересказанные мной в произвольной форме. Нужны ли кавычки? Нужна ли запятая после первой части прямой речи? Нужен ли дефис перед словом "говорит"? Нужен ли дефис перед вторым предложением прямой речи?

**Пример 1:**
*Уходи-ка ты домой, говорит. Да лицо своё умой, говорит.*

**Пример 2:**
*Интересно было узнать, как они мне ответят. Ответили. "Не положено, – говорят. - Эпидемиологическая обстановка не позволяет".*

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в слова "говорит" и "говорят" здесь использованы в качестве вводных (их можно без потери смысла изъять из предложений) .

**1.** Это неполная цитата, поэтому необходимы кавычки, в конце ставится многоточие.
«Уходи-ка ты домой,
Говорит,
Да лицо своё умой,
Говорит...»

**2.** Вы пересказываете чьи-то слова в произвольной форме, добавляете вводное слово "говорят", поэтому считаю, что обозначать прямую речь не нужно.
Я бы написала так:
**— Интересно было узнать, как они мне ответят. Ответили. Не положено, говорят, эпидемиологическая обстановка не позволяет.**

Вот как оформлены такие предложения у Стругацких.

> Ты не думай, **говорит**, мне не жалко, я только удивляюсь, как это в одного такого тощего старика столько горшков самой сытной еды помещается. Ты ешь, **говорит**, но ты мне скажи, может быть, ты все-таки не один у нас в деревне?
> ...отстань ты, **говорит**, от меня, у меня из-за тебя пища в рот не лезет, откуда я знаю — почему?
> Выхаживай, **говорят**, как можешь, выходишь — будет тебе муж, а что он чужой — так ты тоже вроде чужая.

**3.** При обозначении прямой речи всегда используется не дефис, а **тире**.

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)
[Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Улитка на склоне](http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/smena/1988/11/07.html)
[ГОВОРИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
[Корней Чуковский. Мойдодыр](https://www.teremok.pp.ru/Pisateli/Rus_Pisateli/Chukovski/Moi_dodir.htm)